# How do I code a custom ordering function in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

Having

```
<div class="item" data-ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:filterCourses | orderBy:predicate">...
```

and

```
$scope.predicate = function(course) {
    //$scope.orderProp
};
```

what code do I need to put inside the predicate so I can

1. order the same way the default orderBy:predicate will order(not sure if this makes sense)
2. place empty course.StartDate at the end of the list

Notes:

- course is an Object with different  properties like title, startDate,
  code
- $scope.orderProp contains the value to sort by: title, startDate,
  code. When startDate is empty I would like to place those items at
  the end of the list but still keep sorting by date properly, start
  date is an "integer" that I later display with ng-date in nicer form

Thank you

**Answer:**
Here's what I ended up with
http://jsfiddle.net/3hz2j8j7/

Comment: did you try reading the `orderBy` docs?

Comment: saw those but I'm not sure they relate to my problem

Comment: What is the _"default orderBy:predicate"_ ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrderBy can accept a list of predicates (a bit like saying "order by A, then B"). So your first predicate will ensure that blank start dates go at the end, and your second one will use the value of orderProp:

```
<div ... orderBy:[nonEmptyStartDate, orderProp]">

$scope.nonEmptyStartDate = function(course) {
    return course.startDate=="" ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Constantinos answer, I did a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dirakkk/or2tgdgy/1/) for you with your exact data.
All the Angular magic is in

```
<div ng-repeat="course in courses|orderBy:[nonEmptyStartDate,orderProp]:true">
```

Where orderProp='title' so that first data are ordered by non empty date first and then by title.
Please let us know .